# solution to overflowing equation?

Tags: equations, amsmath

What is the best solution for an equation which is overflowing?

I have the structure:

```
\begin{align}
long here & long here 2
\end{align}
```

and this causes the long here 2 to overflow.

I want to put it in the line below, shifted almost all the way to the left. One way to do it might be:

```
\begin{align}
\lefteqn{long here} & \\
& long here 2
\end{align}
```

but I thought there might be a way that wouldn't require lefteqn. is it so?
(by the way, is lefteqn a no-no like eqnarray?)

Comment: what about using the `multline` environment instead of `align`?

Comment: but I do want it to be pushed forward a little (the second line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is the `multline` environment (from `amsmath`):

```
\begin{multline}
long left \\
long right
\end{multline}
```

The `mathtools` package provides also `multlined` that is to `multline` as `aligned` and `gathered` are to `align` and `gather`.